# Selecting and deleting multiple files at once with roxy fieman

Tags: javascript, php, web, roxy-fileman

I am using roxy fileman with ckeditor in one of my websites.
I find it weird that there is no possibility to select multiple files and delete them all at once.

It's really annoying when you have lots of files in a directory and you find yourself forced to delete them one by one.

Did I miss something? Is it doable and I just don't know how to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not build in. Though you could write your own function, you would have to write a part to select multiple files (take a look at the functions  `setFile()` and `getSelectedFile()`) and could run a loop to delete the files at once (take a look at the `deleteFile()` function).